# Hide a div some levels higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

On the left side of my screen I have an index. If you click an item of this index it will show the content on the right side of the page. If you click several of the index items all information belonging to these indexes will be shown. this might be a bit overwhelming for the user so I want the users to be able to close some of the parts on the right side. Therefore I added a button to each part that is shown on the right side. unfortunately it is not working as expected.

I have a snippet of my html page:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106">
   <div class="close-btn-panel">
     <button type="button" class="close-btn" id="close-btn-SUPL106" aria-hidden="true"></button>
   </div>     
   <div class="panel-heading"><h3>header</h3></div>
   <div class="panel-body" >
     <pre>some-text.</pre>
   </div>
  <h3 class="bg-primary"> <img src="cucumber-logo.png" width="32" height="30">Sub Header</h3>
  <p> Some more text here</p> 
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106_1"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106_1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106_2"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106_2" style="display: none;"></div>
...
```

When clikcing the button I would like to close the parent div with id SUPL106. The tricky part is that I have such a button in ever div that looks like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="SUPL106">
```

where the id has a different unique value.

I created a javascript/jquery function to handle the click on the button. the script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( 'button.close-btn' ).click(function() {
    var container = $('this').closest('div').closest('div');
    if(container.eq( $('.panel-default'))) {
        $(container).toggle(200);
        alert("hello");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

This javascript is showing me the alert so I thought it should be working. Although the div did not hide itself. The thing is that if I change the value in the eq() into something completely stupid it is still showing me the alert.

I have been working on this for several days now and can't seem to find a proper solution for it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have 2 `div`s with the same `id` (`SUPL106`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove duplicate IDs in order to get valid HTML markup... Then it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( 'button.close-btn' ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel-default').toggle(200);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it. After I figured out that I had to remove the quotes around the word: this  Thanks.

Comment: @WernervanMook So please consider to mark it as answer so question will be closed